# PHP linking from one page to the next

Tags: php

I am trying to create a small website to sell items on and learn php. I have a index.php which links to a chairs.php page and then from there to a viewItem.php page depending on which item they choose.

I have in my database 4 items. On the chairs.php a while loop runs to display on the page all items in that database.
I would like to use the id of the item to link to the next page but I think the while loop is always going to assign to the variable that I am using the very last entry in that while loop.

Can someone point me in the direction of how I would resolve this? I would like the user to select a Chair 1 on my Chairs.php page with ID 1 in my db to link to the corresponding page. Currently all links on the chairs.php would link to the last item in my while loop which is then assigned to the $_SESSION['output_id'] = $output_id variable.

Thank You

```
<?php 
    
$query = "SELECT * FROM `chairs_table";    
$queryChairs = mysqli_query($connection, $query);   
  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryChairs)) {
    
    $output_id = $row["ID"];
    $output_img = $row["Image"];
    $output_name = $row["Name"];
    $output_desc = $row["Desc"];   
    $output_price = $row["Price"];

$_SESSION['output_id'] = $output_id;    
$_SESSION['output_img'] = $output_img;
$_SESSION['output_name'] = $output_name;
$_SESSION['output_desc'] = $output_desc;
$_SESSION['output_price'] = $output_price;
 
?>  

<div class="itemContainer" onclick="location.href = 'viewItem.php?id=<?php echo "{$output_id}" ?>'" style="cursor:pointer;" >  
    
<div> <img src = "img/<?php echo "{output_img}" ?>"> </div>
<div class="itemTextTitle"><?php echo"{$output_name}" ?></div> 
<div class="itemTextDesc"><?php echo"{$output_desc}" ?></div>
<div class="itemTextPrice">cop <?php echo"{$output_price}"?></div>    
    
</div>      

<?php        
}      
?>   
       
</div>
```

Comment: The code provided should not result in such behaviour since everything is output inside the loop. Have you taken a look at the generated HTML? Are all URLs really the same? What I believe you're doing is using the session data in `viewItem`, rather than the id that you passed in the url. Which would result in faulty behaviour, since you're overwriting the session data in each iteration.

Comment: Follow up advice: don't rely on session data here. There is nothing wrong with making another db query in `viewItem` to get the details of one specific item. Currently, it's like trying to load your entire table into session and using everything from there. This might not be a performance problem if you have four items, but as your inventory grows, it will eventually become one. Also, your db stops being the [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth), meaning you might have inconsistency issues.